# not able to start neo4j server

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am using neo4j version 3.3.1 with java 1.8.0_151 on Windows 10. The log gives the following error:

```
    Invoke-Neo4j : Failed to start service 'Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j (neo4j)'.
    At line:1 char:163
    + ... odule 'C:\neo4j\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j start)
    +                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the path to the java.dll file. I have a 64 bit machine and the file was previously in Program Files(x86) folder although it is the correct version. This was confusing Neo4J.

I just copied the java folder to Program Files and changed the environment variable to point there and it worked.